# Create session and redirect with ApiGateWay

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have several projects and each requires authentication

so I created another one to manage the session for the user and the token Like GateWay or an access point

So, I have to authenticate once
and my session has to pass from one project to another

but I do not know how to do that , is there a way to add a module in this GateWay to create a unique key and transmit it with each redirection or just with JWT ?

I hope you can help me with your advices .

If you need any further information let me know .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can create an API gateway that will manage the authentication part with JWT and manage the services call you need.

The flow will be:

client <-> API gateway (auth check) <-> your services